Disable listview vertical bounces when scrolling to top or bottom by using FMX Delphi 11.2
My APP is developed by using FMX Delphi 11 ,for both iOS and Android. there is an issue for Listview,
I did't enable the 'PullToRefresh' property of the listview, but When scrolling a ListView in iOS device, the ListView bounces more when you scroll and reach the top or bottom of listview.  this only happened in iOS not in Android.
So far I havn't found any property to disable this effect of listview by using Delphi 11.2. something similar like in xCode with swift:
self.myTableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
